# How to show a div for a while before second page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with name ADD . and with this button i want to load a second page in present page with ajaxload. the question is how can i show a div for 4 second before load second page ?and after that 4 second the second page loads?
here is my snippet :

```js
 $(function() {
 $('.add').click(function() {
 $('.here').html('<span class="loading">LOADING...</span>');
 $('.here').load('secondpage.html');
 });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" href="javascript "><div class="add">ADD Zone</div></a>
<div class="here" style="border:1px solid #000; width:100%; height:400px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout`:

```
$(function() {
  $('.add').click(function() {
    $('.here').html('<span class="loading">LOADING...</span>');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.here').load('secondpage.html');
    }, 4000);
  });
});
```